# Flex/AS3 Dynamically Create class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need to create somethink like this.

```
var s:String;
var b1:Boolean;
if (b1==true)
   s="Class1()"
else 
   s="Class2()";
var o:Object;
o = new [s]()   // create or new Class1(), or new Class2
```

Comment: Why does it need to be a string? Why not make an Interface that both Class1 and Class2 implement? Or a Class they both inherit from?

Comment: You can instead create a reference like: ref['myclass'] = MyClass and then simply do new ref['myclass']();

Comment: Thanks, but i have error with this line "var classType:Class = somethingIsTrue ? Class1 : Class2;" 1120: Access of undefined property somethingIsTrue

Comment: Sorry, now i understend what is mean. It's like (Boolean) ? Class1 : Class2;

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much information so I don't know if you really *need* to do this, but there are a few good reasons you might, and it can be done using [`getDefinitionByName`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()):

```
var className:String = somethingIsTrue ? "Class1" : "Class2";
var classType:Class = getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
if (classType)
    trace(new classType());
```

Note that:

- The class name must be fully qualified, meaning if your class is in a package you must include the package. Example: `"path.to.my.stuff.Class1"`
- If there are no "real" references to the class in your code (a string with the class name doesn't count) it will not get compiled into your SWF, and therefor `getDefinitionByName` will not find it. The easiest way to solve this is to put a type declaration somewhere, such as `var a:Class1, b:Class2`. Another way is to put those classes in a `swc` library.
- Using `getDefinitionByName` is very slow (thanks @Philarmon), so to be clear: avoid this unless you really have to do it.

---

**EDIT**: Here's an example of how you can do it *without* using a string:

```
var classType:Class = somethingIsTrue ? Class1 : Class2;
var instance:Object = new classType();
```

As you can see, you don't have to use a string if you actually know the class name ahead of time. In fact cases where you *don't* know the class name ahead of time is rare.

Even if you are starting with a string (say from JSON serialized user data), as long as you know the class names ahead of time you can map the strings to class references:

```
var classes:Object = {
    "alfa": Class1,
    "bravo": Class2
}

var className:String = "alfa";
var instance:Object = new classes[key];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that getDefinitionByName() is dead slow though, so if you need to create a lot of stuff this way, it might be better to pass the class name directly or - if it have to be a string - just do a mapping class that will return a class name based on strings

Comment: Indeed, if there's a way to *not* rely on a string it's certainly better. The OP at this point hasn't made that an option.

Comment: Thanks, but i have error with this line 
"var classType:Class = somethingIsTrue ? Class1 : Class2;"
1120: Access of undefined property somethingIsTrue

Comment: Sorry, now i understend what is mean. It's like (Boolean) ? Class1 : Class2;

Comment: Yeah replace `somethingIsTrue` with your own condition. You don't need to use a ternary, either, you could just do `classType = Class1`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the reasoning behind your situation, most likely what you are looking for is an Interface. First create an interface (see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html) for an example):

```
public interface MyInterface {
  //Include any methods the classes should implement here
}
```

Then each class should implement that interface:

```
public class Class1 implements MyInterface
```

And finally, when creating them, you can do it like this:

```
var o:MyInterface;
if (b1 == true)
  o = new Class1();
else 
  o = new Class2();
```